# How to save a Parse Object that has a reference to a User object?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have a function that creates a new Comment object and saves it to the database. Before saving it the comment text, the id of the object it is attached to, as well as a pointer to the user object that posted the comment are set on the object before it is saved. However when run I get the error:

> Cannot create pointer to unsaved parse object

Here is the code in question:

```
this.postComment = function(comment, objectId) {
   // Get logged in user
   var currentUser = Parse.User.current();

   // extend and create new Comment object
   var Comment = Parse.Object.extend('Comment');
   var comment = new Comment();
   // Set fields to be saved
   comment.set('object', objectId);
   comment.set('commentText', comment);
   comment.set('user', currentUser);

   // Save new comment to db
   comment.save(null, {
      success: function(comment) {
         console.log("success");
      },
      error: function(comment, error) {
         console.log(error);
      }
   });
}
```

This leads me to believe that there is something wrong with the User object that I am pointing to but the User exists in the database and is even retrieved using `Parse.User.current()`

I've looked at other posts with the same error but I have yet to find a solution to this problem. Please let me know if there is any more information I can provide.

Comment: what line are you getting that error? Check on console

Comment: @pratikwebdev The error comes from the comment.save line. I can see an console logs before that line but do not see the success or error function logs.

Comment: could you change the function parameter? Local `comment` to function and `parameter` passed to function are named same and assignment is done with `set`. Check what value is coming in debugger for comment object inside function during `set` statements. Change the parameter first for function definition and try.

Comment: That was it, I can't believe I didn't see it. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Thats great. Code on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the function `parameter` name or handle local `comment` object assignment. Check if it works after.